# JavaFX - Change TableCell column of selected TableRow in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecell

I have a TableView containing a custom column with an image. The other columns get filled by an ObservableList, but not the custom one!

On double-clicking the row, I want to change that image but don´t know how to get that TableCell-object, I only get the ObservableList containing the data of the other columns (look for TODO in my code).

Here´s some sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown")
            );


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> customCol = new TableColumn<>("Status");
        customCol.setMinWidth(200);
        // Install custom cell renderer
        customCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {

                TableCell<Person, String> cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {

                    ImageView image = new ImageView (new Image ("grey.png"));

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem (String item, boolean empty) {

                        super.updateItem (item, empty);

                        if (empty) {

                            setGraphic  (null);
                            setText     (null);
                        }
                        else {

                            setGraphic  (image);
                            setText     (null);
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }

        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, customCol);

        table.setOnMousePressed ((event) -> {

            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {

                System.out.println("double clicked, but dunno know how to change last columns image??");

            // TODO Only returns data of the other columns, but nothing from my custom column ...
            System.out.println(this.table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }



    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }

}
```

Maybe someone could give me advice how to change the image of the last column?

Many thanks and best regards

Wiesi ;)

Comment: If you want to change the image, why not add a new property to `Person`?

Comment: I thought about that, but I don´t know how to reference this value inside my doubleclick-listener and in the updateItem-method inside my cellFactory? Could you please provide a working example?

Comment: You need a cell value factory, as well as a cell factory. The cells in the column need some kind of data to display. You defined the column as a `TableColumn<Person, String>` so you need to provide some string data (though I don't know what you intended here). So what, specifically, are you trying to do? How are you proposing to get the image from the `Person` object? What image do you want to display when the row is double-clicked?

Comment: I don´t want to show any data from Person. In my real-life-app I do some checks when double-clicking a row, depending on the result I want to exchange the image in the column.

Comment: But the result of your checks is, in some sense, data that depends on the item in the row. Perhaps you need to edit your question to make your example closer to the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Basically, define a property in your model class (or, if necessary, elsewhere) that determines the image you want shown for that item. Provide that property from the `cellValueFactory` for your column. When you double click, perform your checks, and if appropriate update the property in the item. Then your cell factory provides a cell which checks the value passed into the `updateItem()` method and chooses the appropriate image to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very precise, but maybe this helps. This example shows a table of `Item`s. It maintains a set of `Item`s that have been validated successfully. (In this example an item is valid if its value is even.) The third column shows an image that is a red rectangle if the item has not been successfully validated (i.e. is not valid, or validation has not been performed) and a green rectangle if it has been validated (i.e. it has an even value and validation has been performed). Double-clicking a row in the table will perform validation on that item if it has not been successfully validated (so double clicking an even-valued item will turn its image green, double clicking an odd-valued item will have no effect). (Double-clicking an already-validated item will remove it from the validated set, which makes testing easier.)

The way it works is to maintain an `ObservableSet<Item>` representing the validated items. The cell value factory returns a boolean binding that observes that set and evaluates to true if the item is in the set and false otherwise. The cell factory just returns a cell that checks the boolean value and sets the appropriate image.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithValidationColumn extends Application {

    private final Image validImage = createImage(20, 20, Color.GREEN);
    private final Image invalidImage = createImage(20, 20, Color.RED);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::valueProperty));

        TableColumn<Item, Boolean> validColumn = new TableColumn<>("Validated");

        ObservableSet<Item> validItems = FXCollections.observableSet();

        validColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Item item = cellData.getValue() ;
            return Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> validItems.contains(item), validItems);
        });

        validColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Item, Boolean>() {
            private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Boolean valid, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(valid, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    if (valid) {
                        imageView.setImage(validImage);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImage(invalidImage);
                    }
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });

        table.getColumns().add(validColumn);

        // validate on double-click:

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if ((! row.isEmpty())  && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    Item item = row.getItem() ;
                    if (validItems.contains(item)) {
                        validItems.remove(item);
                    } else {
                        if (validate(item)) {
                            validItems.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(100)));
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600 ,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean validate(Item item) {
        // items with even values validate:
        return item.getValue() % 2 == 0;
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    private final Image createImage(int w, int h, Color color) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(w, h, color);
        return rect.snapshot(null, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James_D, I was able to abstract this to my needs!